# 3086 error could not delete from specified tables

Tags: sql-server, ms-access-2010

i got this error when i am delete record from ms access form  in sql server data base and table are linked through odbc connection  and delete command written in vb.net please can any one show me solution to this command line written below

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete  from dbo_Main where user =  Forms![frm-Examiner]![coUser] "
```

thanks
ramesh

Comment: Well, you probably got this because you couldn't delete from the tables you specified.

Comment: What does 3086 error mean? What's your query? etc etc

Comment: run time error 3086 in ms access

Comment: @Siyual i have permission to delete records and i manually executed i got deleted

Comment: I really wonder why those 3 "close" votes and those 2 brave anonymous downvotes !

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a permission issue, you could try this:

```
dim sSql as string
sSql = "Delete from dbo_Main where user = '" & Forms![frm-Examiner]![coUser] & "'"
debug.print sSql
DoCmd.RunSQL sSql
```

At least it should give you some hints about what's possibly wrong

Comment: ok. Can you share the statement that the `debug.Print` generated ? (Press ctrl+G to see it)

Comment: Delete  from dbo_Main where user = 'kotra, naresh'

Comment: That's great. So the problem might be the one @HansUp mentionned

Answer (score 1):

User is a [reserved word](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html#U).  Enclose it in square brackets to make sure the db engine treats it as a field name.

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "Delete from dbo_Main where [user] = Forms![frm-Examiner]![coUser] "
```

Comment: Well observed. Perhaps even `where dbo_main![user] =...`. Ah these reserved words :-/

Answer (score 0):

Combine suggestions from @HansUp and @iDevlop

```
dim sSql as string
sSql = "Delete from dbo_Main where [user] = '" & Forms![frm-Examiner]![coUser] & "'"
DoCmd.RunSQL sSql
```

Comment: actually what i observed is  updating and delete statements are not working other than that insert statements working fine  with ms access form with vb.script is it any problem but i have all permissions on database

Answer (score 0):

This error can also occur if the table that's the target of the update/delete is a linked table without a primary key. Add a primary key and relink the table using the Linked Table manager (so Access sees the Primary key).